# Direct image sheaf under an open embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, affine-geometry

Let $i: U=\mathbb A^2-0\to\mathbb A^2=X$ be the inclusion (over a base field $k$). It's well-known that $\mathbb A^2-0$ is not an affine variety and the restriction map $\mathcal O_X(X)\to\mathcal O_X(U)$ is an isomorphism. I want to know if

> $\mathcal O_X\to i_*\mathcal O_U$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Well yeah it is. To see this is is sufficient to check this on open affine subsets, even principal ones isn't it? If that affine subsets does not contains $0$ there is nothing to do, but if it does then $O_X(D(f))\to O_U(i^{-1}(D(f))\simeq O_U(U)_f$ (recall that if $X$ is a (quasi) separated scheme, and $f\in O_X(X)$ then $O_X(X_f)=O_X(X)_f$ where $X_f=\{x\in X, f(x)\neq 0 \Leftrightarrow f_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\}$

Comment: I don't know the last fact you mention ("recall that if..."), where can I find it? I only know that for affines.

Comment: Well I know for sure it's in Liu's book, it must be in EGA for sure, being quasi separated in that case is tantamount to "every intersection of affines subset has a finite cover by affine subsets", since here $U$ is separated the intersection of affine subsets IS affine, so you may readily prove the proposition (I can show you how to do it if you don't).

Comment: Do you know a bit about quasi-coherent sheaves and the fact that under reasonnable conditions (e.g the morphisme being... quasi-separated or being in the noetherian case) the image of a quasi-coherent sheaf is quasi coherent, if so you may circumvent the argument (not surprisingly the quasi-separatedness plays the same role in porving that the image is quasi coherent, as it does in the proof of your result).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I know that. I don't know how it follows from "every intersection of affines subset has a finite cover by affine subsets". Could you show me that?

Comment: It's a bit lengthy, so I'll put it as an answer, ok?

Comment: Sure, thanks! Your 2nd way is easier though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what I said in the comment, here's a proof of the following statement.

Prop: Let $X$ be a scheme, and assume that $X$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated i.e every intersection of two open affine subsets has a cover by a finite number of affine subsets.
Let $f\in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, and let $X_f=\{x\in X| f(x)\neq 0\}$, then $X_f$ is open in $X$ and $\Gamma(X_f, \mathcal{O}_X)\simeq \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)_f$.

Proof:
To see $X_f$ is open, we may assume that $X$ itself is affine, but in that cas $X_f=D(f)$ which is open.
Notice that $f$ is invertible in $\Gamma(X_f, \mathcal{O}_X)$ as it is everywhere locally. We thus have a well defined map $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)_f\to \Gamma(X_f, \mathcal{O}_X)$, we're going to prove that it is an isomorphism.

When $X$ itself is affine, the result is obvious.
Now take $X=\bigcup_i U_i$ with a finite numbre of $U_i$'s, all affine, we have a commutative diagram

$$\begin{matrix}0& \to & \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)_f&\to& \prod_i \Gamma(U_i, \mathcal{O}_X)_f&\to & \prod_{i,j}\Gamma(U_i\cap U_j, \mathcal{O}_X)_f\\
&  & \downarrow& & \downarrow& & \downarrow\\
0& \to & \Gamma(X_f, \mathcal{O}_X)&\to& \prod_i \Gamma(U_{i, f}, \mathcal{O}_X)&\to & \prod_{i,j}\Gamma({U_i\cap U_j}_f, \mathcal{O}_X)\end{matrix}$$
The arrow in the middle is an isomorphism since the $U_i$ are affine, therefore the arrow on the left  is injective. If $X$ is separated you're done, as the arrow on the right also is an isomorphism.

In any case this means that if $Y$ is any scheme covered by finitely many open affine subsets $O_Y(Y)_g\to O_Y(Y_g)$ is injective.

Assume only the quasi separatedness of $X$, then the $U_i\cap U_j$ are themsleves covered by finitely many open subsets, and thus the arrow on the far right is also injective.
But then an easy diagram chasing tells you that the arrow on the left is an isomorphism.

You can use the same ideas to prove that if $f: X\to Y$ is quasi-separated and quasi-compact then the direct image of a quasi-coherent sheaf will still be quasi coherent. I believe this is done in pretty much every reference.

Comment: Very nice and clear!